# Time complexity for c*c?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, big-o, time-complexity

Got time complexity questions here:

```
for i = 1 to n
    if something
        p = p*c
    c = c*c
```

For line 1, the time complexity should be n, but what about line 3 and 4? is that n^2? or n^n?

Comment: what `something` is important.  Is it an operation that takes non-constant time related to `n`, or an other input?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arithmetic operations, like multiplication, are considered `O(1)` (constant time), thus the entire code sample is `O(n)`, since there are `n` constant time operations (`O(1*n)`).

Comment: Thank you Dukeling, I thought for self-multiplying there are special cases

Comment: No, it doesn't matter what you multiply, it's all considered constant time, at least while you use a fixed number of bytes to represent a number (as mentioned in the other answer).

Answer (score 4):

If you are analyzing for x-bit integers then multiplication is considered constant time.

If you are analyzing for theoretical purposes with arbitrarily large integers then the best known algorithm for multiplication is `n*log(n)*2^Θ(log*(n))`. I don't know of any compiler that would use that algorithm for multiplication on any machine though, as in practice it is much slower than many other algorithms (except for unreasonably large numbers) including the standard `O(n²)` algorithm for multiplication you learn in grade 2 or 3.

Comment: thank you for your answer, your answer seems more advanced and I will come back when I am more familiar with algorithms :)

Comment: Note that the numbers to be multiplied need not be dependent on 'n'. The best known algorithm will hence be n * log(m) * 2^theta(log*(m)) where m is the max of the numbers to be multiplied.